# Trim in postgres removes 2 extra characters when a space is given in the string

Tags: sql, postgresql

When i tried the following query it gave me expected results :

```
p=# select trim(trailing '+0300' from '2014-12-02 19:38:30 +0300') ;
        rtrim         
----------------------
 2014-12-02 19:38:30 
(1 row)
```

However, i want to also trim the space, so i tried

```
p=# select trim(trailing ' +0300' from '2014-12-02 19:38:30 +0300') ;
       rtrim       
-------------------
 2014-12-02 19:38:
(1 row)
```

However this removed the last 2 numbers as well (30). Is this expected, or is this a bug ?

Comment: "Remove the longest string containing only the characters" - from the documentation. The order of characters in the first argument does not matter (try `' +:03'` for example).